# Android How to display huge image in high-resolutio

Tags: android, android-imageview

i create one apps can zoom in/out huge image but i use

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();        
// will results in a much smaller image than the original
options.inSampleSize = 3;
```

This is effect resolution .

how to zoom in the image, it will display high-resolution

Thank you

Comment: why your using BitmapFactory.Options ?

Answer (score 0):

This will allow you to get the full width and height of the image in question:

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inJustDecodeBounds = true; // This will make the BitmapFactory only decode the size of the image file, not the "real" contents

Bitmap tempBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile("fileUrl", options);

private int height = options.outHeight; // The height of the original file
private int width = options.outWidth; // The width of the original file
```

Your question is not entirely clear, but if you want to do something like 100%, 50% and 33% zoom, you can use these height and width values to zoom.

Here's an example for 50% zoom:

```
Bitmap croppedBitmap = Bitmap.create(new BitmapFactory.decodeFile("fileUrl"), width / 4, height / 4, width / 2, height / 2); // This will return a cropped version of the original image
```

It would seem that you can also use [`BitmapRegionDecoder`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapRegionDecoder.html), but I have no experience with this API, so I can't help you there. It might work better in practice, though.